# Свойство класса для хранения данных?

Tags: php, классы

Доброго времени суток.

не судите строго, полностью пока не понимаю, что, где и зачем на 100%...

есть достаточно убогий скрипт. Например,
имеем три части (за все отвечают разные файлы, вообще муть...)
title
breadcrumb
content

При переходе на страницу новости, для вытягивания этой новости делается ТРИ запроса! Как наверное догадались как-раз на заголовок(title страницы браузера), хлебные крошки(breadcrumb), и сама новость(контент).
Меня такое, естественно, не устраивает.
И я решил, что проще набросать маленький класс и при переходе к новости пихать все в виде массива в свойство класса, а по скрипту уже тащить все из него.

Т.е. свойство класса имеет, скажем так, условный "буфер". При заходе на страницу все данные в свойстве, а в хлебных крошках и заголовке я уже тяну из него(свойства), избегая запросов.

Нормален ли такой подход? Потому как ничего другого в голову не приходит такого же простого.

**UPD**

Хотя мне пофиг на минусы. Но не люблю когда не пишут причину.
Подумалось, что из-за моего глупого вопроса. Но так же предположил, что из-за отсутствия примера о чем спрашиваю.
Вот пример

```
class News
{
    public $newsArray = array();

    public function __construct() {
        if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {
            $this->get($_GET['id']);
        }
    }

    public function get($id) {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * news WHERE id = '".(int)$id."'");

        if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
            $r = mysql_fetch_array($query);
            $this->newsArray = $r;
            return $r;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

**UPD 2**
Так ни у кого нет идей почему такое плохо и как избежать трех запросов и сделать один, сли данные нужны в трех разных файлах?
Поясните нубу пожалуйста. Ведь не все сразу стали писать мега-код.

Comment: Вообще использовать глобальные переменные таким образом не зер гут

Comment: Я по этому и поинтересовался.
А как тогда поступить, чтобы избежать кучи запросов для вытягивания одного и того же из БД?

Comment: Ну если вы хотите получить 10 новостей одним запросом, то делаете один запрос с что-то типа  WHERE id > $min AND id < $max

Comment: нет. не 10, а 1 всего. При просмотре полной новости делается три запроса. И вот чтобы этого избежать делаю один запрос и пихаю все о новости в $newsArray. А во всех файлах уже просто дергаю что нужно о просматриваемой новости из $newsArray.

Comment: не имею понятия как устроенна ваша бд, но если в таблице news у вас несколько полей и каждое поле это часть новости, то ваш запрос оптимален.    
Только я бы организовал саму новость в виде класса и присвоил бы перменным экземпляра значения из полей. Но это мои тараканы и я вам их не отдам :)

Comment: не важно сколько полей в БД у новости.
Вопрос в том, как избежать трех запросов.

Не очень так же понятно про глобальные переменные. Ведь $newsArray содержит в себе массив только в случае просмотра полной новости. т.е. только на одной странице. грубо-говоря типа кэша временного.
Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте ActiveRecord, слегка модифицировав его. Если используете Model::find_by_id (ищете по идентификатору единственное значение) можно присваивать результаты в массив с ключом идентификатор, если такого такого ключа не существует, а если существует возвращаете элемент массива с таким ключом. Делал такой велосипед в проекте, в котором уже криво использовался AR.

Comment: Спасибо, уже гуглю. Но что-то подсказывает, что будет сложнее варианта изложенного выше.

Но остается вопрос озвученный выше.
Чем плох вариант?
Получается так, что когда человек переходит к прочтению конкретной новости, то в $newsArray записывается массив с данными новости. И в коде я уже из $newsArray в разных файлах легко получаю что нужно.